# previous button is not working in my slideshow code

Tags: javascript

I am creating slideshow code by mixing two codes of w3school example, all other things like next button are working fine. Only previous button (for loading previous image) is not working. I am debugging the JavaScript but not able to find or rectify the bug.

[SlideShow ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEvY7.png)

**/slideshow.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slideshow_style.css">
</head>
<body>


<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container" onmouseover="stop_timeout()" onmouseout="start_timeout()">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
    <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
    <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
    <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Four</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>  
</div>


<script src="slideshow_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/slideshow_script.js**

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    clearTimeout(myTime);
    if(n===1){showSlides(slideIndex += (n-1));}
    if(n===-1){showSlides(slideIndex += n);}
    clearTimeout(myTime);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
      clearTimeout(myTime);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(num) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (num > slides.length) {slideIndex = 0}    
    if (num < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length - 1}
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    myTime = setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); // Change image every 3 seconds
}

function start_timeout() {
    myTime = setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); // Change image every 3 seconds
}

function stop_timeout() {
    clearTimeout(myTime);
}
```

**/slideshow_style.css**

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

I know this is stupid question, but i am stuck. Please help me out, how can i make this code working. Please point out the bug. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the line

```
if(n===-1){showSlides(slideIndex += n);}
```

with

```
if(n===-1){showSlides(slideIndex += (n-1));}
```

Also, just before the two lines

```
if (num > slides.length) {slideIndex = 0}    
if (num < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length - 1}
```

add the following line:

```
if (slideIndex < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length; }
```

Also delete or comment out the two lines beginning `if (num ...)`.

---

To be honest, there are aspects of your code that are confusing and are not helping you.  It seems to me as if you haven't fully understood the code you have written and have just put things in because they seem to make it work.

Once you've got your code working, there's plenty of scope for writing it better.  Take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.